# How can I detect what is blocking some certain keyboard keys?

Tags: usb, keyboard, hardware-failure

After a while (about half an hour) booting up my system, some of my keyboard keys become unresponsive. Their respective **<kbd>Shift+</kbd>**, **<kbd>Ctrl+</kbd>** and **<kbd>Alt+</kbd>** combinations are also unresponsive. Pressing these keys do just nothing. When I restart (or power off and reboot) my system they become active again for a while.

I haven't installed any particular software that remaps the keyboard keys or does anything similar. My operating system is up to date. I'm very careful with viruses, I have Comodo antivirus installed.

I tested this keyboard in another USB port (<s>without restarting the system</s>), and the problem was same.
I plugged (<s>without restarting the system</s>) another keyboard to that USB port (to the one which the problematic keyboard was originally plugged in), and the new keyboard was functioning alright.
EDIT: I tried these tests with restarting system too. The results were the same.

How can I detect what software is causing this in my PC? Or is this just because of my keyboard being broken (a hardware failure)? Do I need to buy a new keyboard?

---

The problematic keys are:

- The <kbd>Left CTRL</kbd> key
- Some certain function keys: <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>
- Two number keys: <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd> (not the ones on the number pad)
- Some special keys: <kbd>Ins</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>
- Some punctuation characters: <kbd>"</kbd> (quote), <kbd>*</kbd> (asterisk), <kbd>-</kbd> (hyphen)

My OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1

Comment: It's either your USB port or the keyboard. Test with another keyboard, and test with this keyboard on another port or computer. Then come back and tell us what happened.

Comment: @RandolphWest I added the test results to my question.

Comment: Are you saying that the new keyboard works? If so, the old one is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - using a new keyboard will tell you if it is a software or hardware problem. I would suggest getting a new keyboard!